# Opera-like UI - Vaadin

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin

For a vaadin application with neo4j database, i get all websites my user using `Match (u:User{_id:<his id>})-[:OWNS]->(s:Site)` and i return all of the sites.

In my UI, i want to do something like Opera's main page using gridlayout.

here is how i do :

```
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(5, 2);
    grid.setCaption("Liste des Sites");
    grid.setSizeFull();
    grid.setMargin(new MarginInfo(false, true, true, true));

    Button addSite = new Button(FontAwesome.PLUS);
    addSite.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_HUGE);
    addSite.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_QUIET);
    addSite.setSizeFull();

    addSite.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            new SiteCreation(); //this shows a modal window
        }
    });
```

then i want to add all of user's sites before the addSite Button, like you can see on opera's UI.

But the problem is, how can i create a clickable layout to set some labels into?
i want the user to have some clickable squares in which he can see the corresponding site's information, and when he clicks on it, he goes to another view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render one site, use a [`Panel`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.8/com/vaadin/ui/Panel.html) and use [`addClickListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Panel.html#addClickListener%28com.vaadin.event.MouseEvents.ClickListener%29) to add a [`MouseEvents.ClickListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.8/com/vaadin/event/MouseEvents.ClickListener.html) to handle the click.  The Panel allows you to add further components ([`setContent`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSingleComponentContainer.html#setContent%28com.vaadin.ui.Component%29) e.g. a `VerticalLayout` and add some image, labels, ..., provide some HTML description, and style them accordingly).